# SSRS Design will not let me edit

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, report-designer

When I open an SSRS report or try to create a new report in Visual Studio 17, it just shows me four columns of two rows, all blank.  It won't let me drag my data over, and if I double-click, the only options are to add/delete rows and colums.

[image]

Comment: Can you choose View your Toolbox? Those spaces are for parameters, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong).  Or how about if you right click in the design area, what comes up in the popup menu?

Comment: Looks like you have a tablix as I can see the grouping. Those columns at the top are for parameters.  Perhaps the design window is too small to see in your screen? close the out put and drag the parameter windows smaller.. it might be hiding in between..

Comment: If I right-click outside the boxes, nothing.  Inside, I just get the option to add or remove columns and rows

Comment: Harry, thank you!!!  Working from home on a small laptop